# How can I get the Green's function of a certain differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

Ho w to extract the green function of the following differential equation. I am trying to extract the analytical form of the green's function.

\begin{align*}
    EI_{zz}\,\frac{\partial ^2u\left(x\right)}{\partial x^2}-\lambda u(x)= f\delta(x-z)\\
f=k*u(x),u(0)=0, u(1)=0
  \end{align*}

The differential equation represents the free vibration of bar or rod with some spring attachment. where k represents the spring constant and lambda is the frequency parameter. The response for any arbitrary value of k is given by the equation below.
\begin{align*}
      u(x)=k*u(z)*G(x,z,\lambda)\\      
\end{align*} 
 but this requires finding $\lambda$ for particular value of k. This can be achived with  solving for  $\lambda$ using below equation, by evaluting x=z.

\begin{align*}
      (1-k*G(z,z,\lambda))*u(z)=0
    \end{align*}
for this equation we will get  $\lambda$. And subistiuing  $\lambda$ in $u(x)$ will given the response of the system.

Below is the reference, but it is a fourth-order of the differential as shown in equation 7. And the solution to it is using green's function.

[image: Green's function]

Comment: Lookup `GreenFunction[]`

Comment: I tried that it is not giving any result. `GreenFunction[{u''[x] - \[Lambda]u[x], u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0}, 
 u[x], {x, 0, 1}, z]`

Comment: @acoustics that didn't work because you typed `\[Lambda]u[x]` rather than `\[Lambda]*u[x]` or `\[Lambda] u[x]`.

Comment: Is the $f\delta(x-\zeta)$ a typo? Also, does $*$ mean `Times` or `Convolve`?

Comment: Currently there exist at least unclear 3 points in your question: 1. Why is there a $\zeta$? Is it a typo? 2. Are you sure the Dirac delta function have a coefficient $f$? I won't say I'm good at using Green's function, but according to what I've learned in textbooks and document of `GreenFunction`, it seems that the right hand side of the PDE should be a Dirac delta function without any coefficient. 3. As already asked in my last comment, what does $*$ mean in your question? `Times` or `Convolve`? If the former, then once again, are you sure it's correct?

Comment: 1. The ζ is a typo, it is actually z.
2. In the differential equation, we can have a coefficient next to a delta function
3.  ∗ mean Times

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. 4. As mentioned above, this is different from what I've learned from text book and document of `GreenFunction`, can you give a reference? Also, if there's really a $f$ before Dirac delta, what's the unit of $G(x,z,\lambda)$ ? 5. Are you aware that, Henrik's solution is for PDE whose right hand side is a Dirac delta function without any coefficient?

Comment: @xzczd  I have added the reference, you asked for. But the only difference is I am trying to find it out for second-order equation.

Comment: …The right hand side of $(8)$ is a single Dirac delta without any coefficient, isn't it?

Comment: @xzczd Yes it is, but the final solution Y(x)  is expressed using green's functions

Comment: …So what? The $f$ is not introduced in that step, it should be used in convolution (rather than multiplication) in later step. Well, with all due respect, I'm afraid you haven't really understood the usage of Green's function. I suggest starting from more basic problem, some good examples can be found in **Applications** section of document of `GreenFunction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
GreenFunction[{EI u''[x] - lamda u[x], u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0},u[x], {x, 0, 1}, z]
(*-((E^(-((Sqrt[lamda] (x + z))/Sqrt[
EI])) (E^((2 Sqrt[lamda])/Sqrt[EI]) - E^((2 Sqrt[lamda] x)/Sqrt[
EI])) (-1 + E^((2 Sqrt[lamda] z)/Sqrt[EI])) HeavisideTheta[
x - z])/(
2 (-1 + E^((2 Sqrt[lamda])/Sqrt[EI])) Sqrt[EI] Sqrt[lamda])) - (
E^(-((Sqrt[lamda] (x + z))/Sqrt[
EI])) (-1 + E^((2 Sqrt[lamda] x)/Sqrt[EI])) (E^((2 Sqrt[lamda])/
Sqrt[EI]) - E^((2 Sqrt[lamda] z)/Sqrt[EI])) HeavisideTheta[-x + 
z])/(2 (-1 + E^((2 Sqrt[lamda])/Sqrt[EI])) Sqrt[EI] Sqrt[lamda])*)
```

Mathematica v12 Windows

**answer to your addon question(comment)**

```
z =.
q[x_, lamda_, z_] =GreenFunction[{u''[x] - lamda u[x], u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0},u[x], {x, 0, 1}, z]
Plot3D[q[x, lamda, .5], {x, 0, 1}, {lamda, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None,AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

There is no solution `P==0, 0<x<1` !

Comment: But right-hand side of the equation is  Dirac delta function, do we need to  put that in equation instead of zero

Comment: `z = 0.5;
q = GreenFunction[{u''[x] - \[Lambda] u[x], u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0}, 
   u[x], {x, 0, 1}, z];
P = Simplify[(1 - 10^12*(q /. x -> z))];
NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < \[Lambda] < 10]` , I am trying to solve for lambda

Comment: Some doubts.
1. why you defined z=.
2. And the second one is for different values of lambda I wanted to plot u[x], essentially my lambdas are my eigenvalues and u[x] are my eigenfunctions.
3.u(x)=k*u(z)*g(x,z,lambda), and k is some constant.

Comment: Some doubts.
1. why you defined z=.
2. And the second one is for different values of lambda I wanted to plot u[x], essentially my lambdas are my eigenvalues and u[x] are my eigenfunctions.
3.`u(x)=k*u(z)*g(x,z,lambda)`, and k is some constant. at ` x=z` the equation reduces to `(1-k*g(z,z,lambda))*u(z)=0`. for non-trivial solution `(1-k*g(z,z,lambda))=0` from this I extract the roots of lambda. But I am not getting roots of lambda

Comment: answer 1: `z` is undefined and only used as  third argument of  `q[x_, lamda_, z_]` answer 2 : The plot shows the function over the paramerrange `x,lamda` (not) answer 3: I don't understand  the meaning of `u[x]`

Comment: `u(x)` is the eigenfunctions of the differential equation in my OP.

Comment: Ok , you asked for the   `GreenFunction` . what is the idea behind the combined use of èigenfunction`and `Green's function? What is the difference between `k`and `lambda`?

Comment: I have made some changes to the OP. Now I understood that you are looking k as wave number. I made a mistake for not  explaining clearly in my original post for what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: If I now understand you right, you try to solve the homogen  problem  `EI u''[x] - lamda u[x]==k u[x]` using the Green's function of   `EI U''[x] - lamda U[x] `???

Comment: Exactly. my mistake not to convey to you properly.

Comment: It's a somewhat strange use of the Greenfunction. why didn't you solve  the problem  `EI u''[x] - lamda u[x]==k u[x]` directly?

Comment: But the right-hand side I have dirac-delta function know? thats why I thought of using green's function. I saw in the literature they used for the fourth oder differential equation. I wanted to Implement to the second-order equation

Comment: Please correct your initial probelm `u[z]` on the right hand side seams to be wrong!